# npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

I am installing node.js on a CentOS 7 server, and am getting the following error when I try to install yeoman:

```
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been  
reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
```

The install of yeoman seems to otherwise work correctly.  Is there something that I can do to avoid this warning?  What are the implications of leaving it unhandled?

Here is the rest of the first part of the terminal output from the yeoman install:

```
[root@localhost ~]# npm install -g yo
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
/usr/bin/yo -> /usr/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js

> yo@1.6.0 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/yo
> yodoctor
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system
✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
Everything looks all right!
/usr/lib
.... many lines of directory structure follow
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that the version of npm that is bundled with the "latest stable" version of node does not properly install some of our npm packages. To fix this, open a command prompt and run:

```
npm -g install npm
```

To update npm to the latest version. This should fix the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem on fresh installation of node & npm. `npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm` The problem occurs also after updating npm to latest version. I checked in on Windows 10 and virtual machine with Debian.

Comment: Even I am facing a similar issue and it does not solve even after updating the npm. I am running it on Windows 10

Comment: I still get this same warning after installing npm@latest.

Comment: same here. node v4.4.7, npm 2.15.8, same warning when trying to install yo

Comment: Same here, after installing last version (7.2.0 x64) in W10

Comment: after running this I'm getting the same message again. Does anybody knows a versin that be used as stable?