# Unable to run aspnet after installing on mac

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, asp.net-core, .net-core

After last step of the command for installing .net core.
**"npm install -g generator-aspnet"**
I am still unable to run **"yo asp net" command**.

[image]

I searched a lot. But didn't find any solution and i have no idea that why i am unable to run the asp net project creation after doing the steps successfully.
I am using mac version 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to install yeoman first and then another required stuff for [generator-aspnet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet):

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g bower
npm install -g generator-aspnet
yo aspnet
```

Comment: after running this 
"npm install -g yo" i got this error
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq Try that command `npm -g install npm`. The problem is that the version of npm that is bundled with the "latest stable" version of node does not properly install some of our npm packages. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35506386/1821692)

Comment: thank you for this ... But after this "npm install -g generator-aspnet
"..... I am still getting this error ....""
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue""

Comment: please check the other answer :(

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq I'll try to check it later

Comment: @AhsanUlHaq OK, I got the same issue `npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue`. However `yo aspnet` works fine. Is `yo aspnet` works on your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ sudo npm -g install generator-aspnet
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠼ normalizeTree: sill install loadCurrentTree
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠋ normalizeTree: sill install loadCurrentTree
⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ fetchMetadata: verb afterAdd /Users/ahsanulhaq
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2         or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/Users/ahsanulhaq/.npm-packages/lib
└── generator-aspnet@0.2.1 

Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ $ npm update minimatch
-bash: $: command not found
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ npm update minimatch
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ npm -v minimatch 3.10.3
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ $ npm install -g npm@3 -bash: $:command not found
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ npm install -g npm@3/Users/ahsanulhaq/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/ahsanulhaq/.npmpackages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/Users/ahsanulhaq/.npm-packages/lib
└── npm@3.10.6 

Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ $ npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2-bash: $: command not found
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2
/Users/ahsanulhaq/.npm-packages/lib
└─┬ minimatch@3.0.2 
  └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
    ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
    └── concat-map@0.0.1 

Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ $ npm -v minimatch -bash: $: command not found
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ npm -v minimatch 3.10.3
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$ yo aspnet -bash: yo: command not found
Ahsans-MacBook-Pro:~ ahsanulhaq$
```